# Select data from different tables limit 10, while the other table limit 5

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to use a MySQL query to select data from three tables, as following:

> **pv**
>   t_id
>   t_name
>
> **pv_values**
>   v_id
>   t_id
>   value
>   datetime
>
> **alm**
>   alm_id
>   t_id
>   datetime
>   status
>   priority

I want to get the last 10 values from `pv_values` for the last 5 rows of `alm` that have priority "1", and also get the name from `pv` for those values.

This is my query, but it only gives me the 10 last values of the last `alm` value:

```sql
SELECT pv_values.*, pv.tag_name
FROM `pv_values`,`pv`
WHERE pv_values.`tag_id` = (
    SELECT `tag_id`
    FROM `alarms` as `alt`
    WHERE `alt`.`tag_id` = `pv`.`tag_id` and `alt`.`priority` = 1
    ORDER BY `alarm_id` DESC
    LIMIT 1
)

Limit 10
```

I expect to get:

```
pv_values.v_id pv_values.t_id pv_values.value pv_values.datetime pv.t_name 
1              1
2              1
3              1
4              1
5              1
6              1
7              1
8              1
9              1
10             1
1              2
2              2
3              2
4              2
5              2
6              2
7              2
8              2
9              2
10             2
```

where `t_id` came from the `alm.t_id` last 5.

Comment: could you please  build an example, because limit 10 means you only would get 10 rows not 20 as you expected

Comment: I want to get 10 rows from pv_values for each 1 in alm

Comment: so the total for rows will be 5*10 = 50 rows that every 5 rows from pv_values will match 1 tag_id from alm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to work with with Data that you select, so that you can understand it better, waht i am doing, when you recognized algorithsm.

So with this data

```
CREATE TABLE alarmes
    (`ID` int, `tag_id` int,  `alarm` varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO alarmes
    (`ID`,`tag_id`,  `alarm`)
VALUES
    (1,1,  'Alarm1'),
    (2,2, 'Alarm2'),
    (3,3,  'Alarm3'),
    (4,4,  'Alarm4')
;
CREATE TABLE pv_values
    (`ID` int, tag_id int ,  `values` varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO pv_values
    (`ID`, `tag_id`, `values`)
VALUES
    (1,1 , 'value1'),
    (2, 1, 'value2'),
    (3, 1, 'value3'),
    (4, 1, 'value4'),
    (5,1 , 'value5'),
    (6, 1, 'value6'),
    (7, 1, 'value7'),
    (8, 1, 'value8'),
    (9,1 , 'value9'),
    (10, 1, 'value10'),
    (11, 1, 'value11'),
    (12, 1, 'value12'),
    (1,4 , 'value1'),

    (2, 5, 'value2'),
    (3, 4, 'value3'),
    (4, 4, 'value4'),
    (5,4 , 'value5'),
    (6, 4, 'value6'),
    (7, 4, 'value7'),
    (8, 4, 'value8'),
    (9,4 , 'value9'),
    (10, 4, 'value10'),
    (11, 4, 'value11'),
    (12, 4, 'value12'),
        (1,2 , 'value1'),
    (2, 2, 'value2'),
    (3, 2, 'value3'),
    (4, 2, 'value4'),
    (5,2, 'value5'),
    (6, 2, 'value6'),
    (7, 2, 'value7'),
    (8, 2, 'value8'),
    (9,2, 'value9'),
    (10, 2, 'value10'),
    (11, 2, 'value11'),
    (12, 2, 'value12'),
    (1,3 , 'value1'),
    (2, 3, 'value2'),
    (3, 3, 'value3'),
    (4, 3, 'value4'),
    (5,3 , 'value5'),
    (6, 3, 'value6'),
    (7, 3, 'value7'),
    (8, 3, 'value8'),
    (9,3 , 'value9'),
    (10, 3, 'value10'),
    (11, 3, 'value11'),
    (12, 3, 'value12')
;
```

You can use in mysql 5.x this statement

```
SELECT rnk, t1.`tag_id`, `values`,alarm
FROM
(Select 
  *
  ,IF(@tag_id<>tag_id, @rank := 0, @rank := @rank +1) rnk
  ,@tag_id := tag_id
From pv_values,(SELECT @rank := 1) r,(SELECT @tag_id := 0) re
Where tag_id in (SELECT tag_id FROM alarmes)) t1 inner join alarmes alm on alm.tag_id = t1.tag_id  
WHERE rnk < 10;
```

or With this for mysql 8.x

```
SELECT rnk, t1.`tag_id`, `values`,alarm
FROM
(Select 
  *
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
 PARTITION BY tag_id
ORDER BY tag_id ASC) rnk
From pv_values
Where tag_id in (SELECT tag_id FROM alarmes)) t1 inner join alarmes alm on alm.tag_id = t1.tag_id  
WHERE rnk < 11;
```

In both cases you get

```
rnk     tag_id  values  alarm
0       1       value1  Alarm1
1       1       value2  Alarm1
2       1       value3  Alarm1
3       1       value4  Alarm1
4       1       value5  Alarm1
5       1       value6  Alarm1
6       1       value7  Alarm1
7       1       value8  Alarm1
8       1       value9  Alarm1
9       1       value10 Alarm1
0       2       value1  Alarm2
1       2       value2  Alarm2
2       2       value3  Alarm2
3       2       value4  Alarm2
4       2       value5  Alarm2
5       2       value6  Alarm2
6       2       value7  Alarm2
7       2       value8  Alarm2
8       2       value9  Alarm2
9       2       value10 Alarm2
0       3       value1  Alarm3
1       3       value2  Alarm3
2       3       value3  Alarm3
3       3       value4  Alarm3
4       3       value5  Alarm3
5       3       value6  Alarm3
6       3       value7  Alarm3
7       3       value8  Alarm3
8       3       value9  Alarm3
9       3       value10 Alarm3
0       4       value1  Alarm4
1       4       value3  Alarm4
2       4       value4  Alarm4
3       4       value5  Alarm4
4       4       value6  Alarm4
5       4       value7  Alarm4
6       4       value8  Alarm4
7       4       value9  Alarm4
8       4       value10 Alarm4
9       4       value11 Alarm4
```

As you can see it is selected 10 Rows for every tag_id.

this is made by giving all rows for every tag_id a rownumber and then select the first 10.

You have to join your table `pv`  and ordering pv_values to your needs.

Comment: but the name of alarm (Alarm1,2,3) is not in alarms table it is in a table called pv so there must connection between 3 tables not only 3

Comment: Look i showed you, without any data how you can make it . If you have difficulties to adept it to your structure, please make a dbfiddle example(Which you should have made in the first place) with your data  and i will see what i can do.